# EaselJS : I'm trying to understand how Cross Domain works with bitmaps

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm very new to javascript and EaselJS and I've searched the documentation as well as the questions here and I've learned that my initial problem with my mouse events not working with my bitmaps was because I'm trying to use bitmaps from a filepath on my computer.

I understand now that I need to use img.crossOrigin to allow easeljs to work with these images, but even though I'd added this, I still can't get this to work.

Here's what I have:

```
function init(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('game'); //assign canvas to variable
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var term = new Image();
    term.src = 'terminal.png';
    term.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; 

var oswin = new Image();
    oswin.src = 'frame.png';
    oswin.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

var terminal = new createjs.Bitmap(term);
        terminal.x = 28;
        terminal.y = 36;
        terminal.name = "terminal";
        stage.addChild(terminal);

var oswindow = new createjs.Bitmap(oswin);
        stage.addChild(oswindow);
        oswindow.x = 196;
        oswindow.y = 5;
        oswindow.name = "oswindow";

        //hide this bitmap 
        oswindow.visible = false;

//onclick to unhide the bitmap
terminal.on("click", handleClick);

stage.update();
}

function handleClick(){
    oswindow.visible = true;
    stage.update();

    }
```

I've added in the crossOrigin and unfortunately, this still doesn't work and I've no idea why because I don't understand cross domain very well despite reading on it. (I'm a beginning programmer)

I work entirely offline right now, just trying to learn, so a way to fix this would be really nice.

Comment: what browser you using to test with? you will need to load it with some extra permissions to allow file access from the browser.

Comment: The crossOrigin flag only works for servers that send the allow-access header. To work locally, I recommend a local server like XAMPP or MAMP.

Comment: @chrisvanhooser I use chrome to test my work in!

Comment: @Lanny thank you! I'll look into those right now!